# XCode 'Run Script' step to create directory and copy file is failing

Tags: xcode4, run-script

I have the following custom script step during my build:

mkdir -p "${CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH}/Frameworks"
cp "${SRCROOT}/testing.1.dylib" "${CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH}/Frameworks"

The script runs successfully, but when I check the bundle the Frameworks directory does not exist.

Should not not work as I expect? (Frameworks folder created with the testing.1.dylib in it).

Edit: Added screenshot of the runscript.
[image: RunScript]

Answer (score 1):

How about trying the following:

```
dst=${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH}/Frameworks
mkdir -p "${dst}"
cp "..." "$dst"
```

(I found your example and adapted it as above to copy a dylib into the 'Frameworks' folder of my framework).